# Allowed memory size of 1048576000 bytes exhausted - Woocommerce order details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, memory-limit

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1048576000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79695872 bytes) in /home/shopkeywest/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3720

This error appears when I try to see the order details:

http://www.mywebsite.ca/wp-admin/post.php?post=77736&action=edit

I've added more memory `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` and `ini_set('max_execution_time', '500');`

Also I've tried with `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

I think this is not a memory issue, because I have more than 4 gb free on my server.

Comment: Are you sure those settings are working? Maybe try [these steps](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-wp-includes-folder-functions-php-line-346/) in increase the memory. Or by editing the wp-config.php file [mentioned here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/fix-wordpress-memory-exhausted-error-increase-php-memory/)

Comment: Hello John, thanks for reply my question. I've tried them but it's still not working, because this issue only appears when I go to see the order details.

Comment: 1048576000 bytes are 1000M, by setting it to 512M you're actually reducing it, aren't you?